# VBA - Unable to get TextBoxes Property of Worksheet Class

Tags: vba, excel

Fairly new to VBA and I just started encountering the error `Unable to get TextBoxes Property of Worksheet Class`.

It highlights the following line:

`ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("txtFilePath").Text = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"`

The mystery to me is that I know this line was working before without any problems. The only thing I could think of is that I was messing with protecting the sheet, but even now that it is unprotected I still get the error. I've also tried the following solution, but encounter the same error:

`ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("txtFilePath").Object.Text = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"`

Can anyone explain to me why I am encountering the error and why I started encountering it so randomly? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question. Figured it out by accident.

The problem was that I had my textbox (txtFilePath) grouped together with another textbox on my worksheet. When I ungrouped them everything worked fine. Can anyone explain to me why the grouping would make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly enough, there is no clear way on how to access the properties of a grouped shape (a group is basically a shape, at least in 2010). There are two possible solutions to go about this.

One is obviously to ungroup the textboxes, access the textbox in question and modify it, then regroup them. However, this will prove to be difficult to track as the Group number increases with every regroup that you do. This can pose a potential problem if you have multiple groupings.

The other way, surprisingly enough, is to do it the 'dirty' way, which is basically what the macro recorder gives us in a nutshell. The way to do it is to select the shape itself and to change the text directly, emulating a direct click-and-type motion manually. I've tested it and it works, even when the textbox in question is grouped multiple times.

```
Sub Macro3()

    foo = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("txtFilePath")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = foo

End Sub
```